# finding session state tag in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, web-config, session-state

I need to write a function, where I have to find session state tag/setting in web.config of an application.

I will be passing `web.config` file as a parameter to this function and function should detect the tag and delete it, then should return `web.config` without session state tag in it.

Can I have some functionality or regex to achieve this?

Session tag format:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424" />
```

or

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424"></sessionState>
```

Comment: Session tag format: 

<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424" />

or

<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424"></sessionState>

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for extract viewstate, you can modify this to pull the session state.

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, "<div\\s*class=\"aspNetHidden\"[\\s\\S]*?<\\/div\\>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This is the regex for Session state :

**Regex** (Tested on regexhere.net)

```
<sessionState\s*mode=\"StateServer"\s*stateConnectionString=\"tcpip=([^"]+)"\s*\/>
```

**Input**

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424" />
```

You can make a function to read the webconfig and then replace the state string using regex.replace [Not tested personally]

Comment: I am not sure about how view state is getting extracted from this regex, Can you please provide Regex to extract session state.

You can use regex101.com and add the session state tags given in my comment box?

I am trying for the proper Regex, but still not getting.
If you can also explain the variables used in your answer?

Comment: This wont work. This is hard coding kind of thing.

I can have syntaxes like 1. <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424" />

2. <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424"></sessionState>

3. <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424">
</sessionState>

This all tags should get detected by only 1 Regex.